# Spans of Orthogonal complements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be  the matrix $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1&-1 \\
        1 & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
,$$ let $W$ = ker $A$ and let $W^\bot$ be the
orthogonal complement for W in $\Bbb{R}^4$.

(a) Find orthonormal bases for $W$ and $W^\bot$.

I found $W=span \{(3,-2,-0,1),(0,1,1,0)\} \;$  by evaluating $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&1&-1&-1&0\\
      0 & 1 & -1 & 2&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

but what I don't understand is why span of $W^\bot$ are the two rows of the row-echelon matrix i.e. $W^\bot=span \{(1,1,-1,-1),(0,1,-1,2)\} \;$. I've spent hours but can't figure out the connection of $W^\bot$and those two rows. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its null-space. $\boldsymbol{Ax}$ can be written as a column of inner products of each row with $x$. Therefore, $\boldsymbol{Ax} = 0$ iff $\boldsymbol{x}$ is orthogonal to each row of the matrix.

You reduce it to row-echelon form just to ensure you don't include dependent rows in your basis.